# qemu: hugepages for guest memory

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, libvirt, huge-pages

`qemu-kvm` is launched with `-mem-prealloc -mem-path /mnt/hugepages/libvort/qemu` parameters. Does this mean that the guest memory will be allocated from the hugepages on the host?

Also, libvirt defines the following in domain xml:

```
<memoryBacking>
    <hugepages/>
    <locked/>
</memoryBacking>
```

This basically tells the hypervisor to use `hugepages` for its guest memory, and these pages will be locked in the host's memory (not allowed to be swapped out).

Are these options work together (`-mem-prealloc` and libvirt's xml directive), and one supplement the other?

Comment: My subjective opinion: Forget hugepages, it causes more trouble than it helps. Very likely that host hugepages will be also hugepages in the guest, making your whole memory management sub-optimal. In prod environments I intentionally compiled out hugepages support from my kernels on this reason, but fine-tuned ksm and zswap very accurately. And it is fine.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica, thanks for feedback. Do you mean that _any_ hugepage allocated on the host might also be a hugepage _inside_ of guests, so it will be shared?

Comment: If you have kvm, that means that you have kernel support to map guest resources to host resources. Including pages. Mapping 512 ordinary (4kB) guest pages to a single 2M host page looks possible for me, but it is surely not easy, and currently even swapping, compressing or samepage-merging of 2MB pages is not implemented in the Linux kernel. (For windows, probably about 10 people on the world knows if it were, but probably it also was not, and probably on the same reason).

Comment: Hugepages are good if you need to do many page operations (page operations are essentially: 1. mapping into a process address space 2. mapping out 3. allocate free page 4. free allocated page). That is wonderful but if you can not swap them, if you can not samepage merge them, then which operations could it accelerate?

Comment: However, all the distro-default kernels I know, support samepages (and tend to not support zswap/ksm). So it is my personal opinion, we have a hardware feature what we do not really need, but not implementing it would be PR disaster. So it is implemented but no one thinks it really seriously.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica, but _<locked/>_ directive guarantees that hugepages won't be swapped out? Also, I briefly read about KSM and it sounds like it requires application change (`madvice()` system call etc.), so every application in VM has to be updated?

Comment: I don't know. I don't use libvirt because it does not support lvm volumes as flat VM disks and otherway it is rigid. This is why I wrote comments and not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<hugepages/>`  element will cause guest RAM to be allocated from the default huge pages size pool, and will cause immediate allocation of those huge pages at QEMU startup. Huge pages are *always* locked into host RAM.

The `<locked/>` element is used to control other QEMU memory allocations that are separate from guest RAM. It ensures all non-guest RAM pages are also locked into host RAM.

If you are *not* trying to overcommit host RAM, then using huge pages on the host side is a very good idea for maximizing performance as it improves page table hit rates. This is true regardless of whether the guest OS in turn uses huge pages. This performance benefit will apply to all workloads and all guest OS.

The KSM feature for when you *are* trying to overcommit host RAM (ie run many guests whose total RAM exceeds available host RAM). It tries to share RAM pages between guests to avoid risk of swapping during overcommit. KSM has a quite significant penalty in CPU consumption though, so its a tradeoff as to whether it is useful for a particular workload and/or guest OS.